# Poco compilation error cannot find -lPocoDataMySQL

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I am using ubuntu 16 and installed poco library via apt-get install libpoco-dev (version 1.3).

I also have mysql client installed.

However, when I compile a cpp to test mysql connection, the compiler threw error:
cannot find lPocoDataMySQL
cannot find lPocoJSON

it seems it cannot find the lib for the above two

I have already included the following in Makefile

LD_INCLUDE=-I/usr/include/Poco
CPPFLAGS=-Wno-multichar -Wall -lPocoUtil -lPocoFoundation -lPocoJSON -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoData -lPocoDataMySQL -lPocoJSON

g++ -o dbconnector dbconnector.cpp $(LD_INCLUDE) $(CPPFLAGS)

thanks.

Comment: See Changelogs of Poco Library. PocoJSON was introduced at 1.5 version. PocoDataMySQL started with 1.4.1 version. So how do you want to use them with 1.3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the notes. apt-get on Ubuntu 16.0 only gives me version 1.3. I might need to install the lib manually. I will try and provide updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by install Poco 1.8.

thanks rafix07

Comment: Package: libpoco-dev
Version: 1.8.0.1-1ubuntu4
Priority: optional
Section: universe/libdevel
Source: poco
Origin: Ubuntu